# How to check if a value exists in an array type column using SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am having a bigquery table with many columns including one array type column of zero or many integers.

For instance:

```
WITH sequences AS
  (SELECT [0, 1, 2, 3, 5] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT [2, 4, 8, 16, 32] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT [5, 10] AS some_numbers)
SELECT *
FROM sequences

+---------------------+
| some_numbers        |
+---------------------+
| [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]     |
| [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]   |
| [5, 10]             |
+---------------------+
```

Using BigQuery SQL, I want to generate another column `exists` if any value of tuple (3, 10) is included in `some_numbers` arrays.

My desired output:

```
+--------------------+--------+
| some_numbers       | exists |
+--------------------+--------+
| [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]    | True   |
| [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]  | False  |
| [5, 10]            | True   |
+--------------------+--------+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select format('%T', some_numbers) some_numbers,
  (select count(1) > 0
    from t.some_numbers number
    where number in (3, 10)
  ) as exist
from sequences t
```

when applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: I used `format('%T', some_numbers)` just for the sake of formatting output of array - but you might use just `some_numbers` instead

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail's solution is nice but, in my humble opinion, the below query is cleaner:

```
select format('%T', some_numbers) some_numbers,
  EXISTS(select *
    from t.some_numbers number
    where number in (3, 10)
  ) as exist
from sequences t
```